# How to do ng-repeat through an array of objects?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
   $scope.mydata= [
      {
        "_id": "5fc9e4cc8acc",
        "_rev": "1-deeb3c992677",
        "contacts": [
          {
            "Name": "A",
            "role": "Lead ",
            "ID": "aaa@gmail.com",
            "ID2": "aaaa@ymail.com"
          },
          {
            "Name": "B",
            "role": "Lead ",
            "ID": "aaa@gmail.com",
            "ID2": "aaaa@ymail.com"
          },
          {
            "Name": "C",
            "role": "Lead ",
            "ID": "aaa@gmail.com",
            "ID2": "aaaa@ymail.com"
          },
          {
           "Name": "D",
            "role": "Lead ",
            "ID": "aaa@gmail.com",
            "ID2": "aaaa@ymail.com"
          }
        ],
        "Profiles": [
          {
            "uid": "00",
            "building": "GRAY",
            "location": "Johannesburg",
            "id": "bbb",
            "_rev": "1-130d25d6cf4ecf0c2f2ed55c46b468cb",
            "email": "",
            "name": "zzz",
            "role": "Lead ",
            "office_phone": "112233"
          },
          {
            "uid": "00",
            "building": "GRAY",
            "location": "Johannesburg",
            "id": "bbb",
            "_rev": "1-130d25d6cf4ecf0c2f2ed55c46b468cb",
            "email": "",
            "name": "zzz",
            "role": "Lead ",
            "office_phone": "112233"
          }

          {
            "role": " Network"
          },
        ],
        "codename": "Random"
        "List": [
          "000-7890",
          "000-78901",
          "000-78902",
          "000-78903",
          "000-78904",
        ],

        "Date": "1/7/2016",
        "contact_Name": "yyy",
        "role": "Submitter",
        "sales_Stage": "",
        "Country": "South Africa",

      }
    ]
```

This is the $scope variable i have.In my template i have to display the details like name and role.But im using multiple ng-repeats.Im not sure which is the best way to access it.

Now i have to display the Name and role in "contacts" . How can i use ng-repeat to loop through it . If anyone knows please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use;

```
<div ng-repeat="var in mydata.contacts">{{var.Name}} & {{var.role}}</div>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Are you sure that you have your variable names correct?, If you're using a web browser - use f12 for developer tools, go to the console and see if there are errors.

Answer (score 1):

You will need nested **ng-repeat** because you need to collect information from two sub properties property **i.e.** contacts's role and name, Profiles's role and name which are property of myData so try this:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in myData">
    <div ng-repeat="contact in data.contacts">
       {{contact.Name}} & {{contact.role}}
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="pro in data.Profiles">
         {{pro.name}} & {{pro.role}}
    </div>
</div>
```